# .htaccess include file in php with get variable

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to use .htaccess to change the url and also include the page with php

old: http://website.com?page=test

new: http://website.com/test

```
<?php include 'pages/'. $_GET['page'] . '.php'; ?>
```

I have no idea where to start with .htaccess but any help will be great, thanks :]

Comment: See [`mod-rewrite`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info) for some examples. Ask if you have a specific problem, not a general tutoring inquiry.

Comment: You might want to whitelist what can be in `$_GET['page']` before you insert it into a string like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, with this the user should see `http://domain.com/thepage` and the server would understand the request as `http://domain.com/?page=thepage`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ ?page=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php include 'pages/'. $_GET['page'] . '.php'; ?>
```

alone is very hacker friendly. you should start by limiting the options to allowed files.
i.e. tap to /index.php internally and preset a series of valid options. that said,
depending on the number of files, a preset hardcode may be your best option.

i believe you mean mod_rewrite.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html

adding to /.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=test$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /test [NC,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

or more dynamic

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /%1/ [NC,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

my best suggestion would be to internally send everything to /index.php then via some php parsing/validation, send to a switch() of valid option and a safe default with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```